# Can I tell mpd to add the currently playing song to a specific playlist?

Tags: mpd

I used to do this with spotify. I like to have topic or mood specific playlists, such as "gym" or "studying". So when listening to random music, and finding a song that I think would fit into one of such playlists, I could ask spotify to send the song to a specific playlist.

As far as I can tell, mpd only allows me to edit the "current" playlist, which some other players call the "queue", and potentially overwrite an existing playlist when saving it. So I could "crop" the current song, "add" the necessary playlist, and then "save" the playlist. But this way I lose whatever playlist I was listening to before; and I would like to continue listening to it.

Can I emulate my spotify-ish work flow with mpd in some fashion?

Comment: What client do you use?

Comment: I use mpc and ncmpcpp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply pressing "a" in ncmpcpp will bring up a screen where you can select a playlist to add the currently playing (or selected) item to.

Comment: Any way to do that with mpc?

Answer (score 0):

This will add the currently playing song to a playlist defined in the code. It requires libmpdclient.

1. edit below code with your defines and save to file (e.g. add-to-mpd-playlist.c)
2. gcc or clang with lmpdclient flag (e.g. clang add-to-mpd-playlist.c -o add-to-mpd-playlist -lmpdclient)
3. run binary (e.g. ./add-to-mpd-playlist)

Further improvements include allowing arguments and/or a config file for host,port,pass,playlist. [libmpdclient doc](https://www.musicpd.org/doc/libmpdclient/dir_89dd766eb2df7d7257dbe806a34404af.html) is your friend.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpd/client.h>

//D(x) function for debug messages
//#define DEBUG
#ifdef DEBUG
#define D(x) do { x; } while(0)
#else
#define D(x) do { } while(0)
#endif

#define HOST "YOUR_HOSTNAME"
#define PORT YOUR_PORTNUMBER //usually it's 6600
#define PASS "YOUR_PASSWORD" //comment out if no password
#define PLAYLIST "PLAYLIST_NAME_TO_ADD_CURRENT_SONG_TO"

struct mpd_connection* conn(){
    D(printf("%s %s\n","Connecting to",HOST));
    const char* host = HOST;
    unsigned port = PORT;
    struct mpd_connection* c = mpd_connection_new(host,port,0);

    enum mpd_error err = mpd_connection_get_error(c);
    if(err != 0){
        printf("Error code: %u. View error codes here: https://www.musicpd.org/doc/libmpdclient/error_8h.html\n",err);
        return 0;
    }

    #ifdef PASS
    const char* pass = PASS;
    if(mpd_run_password(c,pass) == false){
        printf("%s\n","Bad password");
        return 0;
    }
    #endif

    D(printf("%s %s\n","Connected to",HOST));
    return c;
}


int main(){
    struct mpd_connection* c = conn();
    if(c == 0) return -1;

    struct mpd_song* curr = mpd_run_current_song(c);
    const char* curr_uri = mpd_song_get_uri(curr);
    D(printf("Currently playing: %s\n",curr_uri));

    if(mpd_run_playlist_add(c,PLAYLIST,curr_uri)){
        printf("%s %s %s %s\n","Added",curr_uri,"to playlist",PLAYLIST);
    }
    else{
        printf("%s\n","Some error");
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I put a few checks and a bit of debug as well; do with the code as you wish.